# How can I wrap a children properties with a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, express, hash

I would like to wrap each child of an object with a function as below.

Is there any solution to make a function or something else to do this not manually?

```
// current code
import authController from "./authController";
import appController from "./appController";
import userController from "./userController";
import postController from "./postController";
import { executeRequest } from "./utils";

const controllers = {
    user: { save: executeRequest(userController.save), 
            confirm: executeRequest(userController.confirm) },
    post: {
        save: executeRequest(postController.save),
    },
    auth: {
        signin: executeRequest(authController.signin),
        signout: executeRequest(authController.signout),
    },
    app: {
        get: executeRequest(appController.get)
    }
```

I would like to use the object like this

```
// expectation
import authController from "./authController";
import appController from "./appController";
import userController from "./userController";
import postController from "./postController";
import { executeRequest } from "./utils";

// do something here to wrap the children

const controllers = {
   user: userController,
    auth: authController,
    post: postController,
    app: appController
};
```

```
import controllers from "../controllers";

const postController = controllers.post;
router.post(Routes.DEFAULT, postController.save);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Although I have a technique that I think would help, I really don't feel inclined to share it until you demonstrate some effort of your own.  What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all the properties in all your imports and send them via the `executeRequest` function.

```
let controllers = {
   user: userController,
    auth: authController,
    post: postController,
    app: appController
};


controllers = Object.keys(controllers).reduce((cAcc, cCurr) => {
   
    cAcc[cCurr] = Object.keys(controllers[cCurr]).reduce((mAcc, mCurr) => {

       mAcc[mCurr] = executeRequest(controllers[cCurr][mCurr]);
       return mAcc;

     }, {})

     return cAcc;
}, {})
```

At this point your `controllers` object will have all the controllers with their methods sent through the `executeRequest` function.